# 2D Sérsic equation

Tags: astrophysics, computational-physics, galaxies, software

The 1D Sérsic equation for disk galaxies is $I(r) = I_0 \exp[{-(r/h)^{1/n}}]$

I'm testing some profile extraction and fitting routines on 2D models and I just can't get my head around transforming it to 2D!

My process is to calculate the ellipse radius of each point I'm trying to calculate and then calculate the Sérsic profile for them.

So far I have (for an ellipse inclined at angle $i$ with ellipticity $e = a/b$):

1. equations for an ellipse: $x = a\cos(\theta - i)$ and $y = b\sin(\theta - i)$
2. $y/x = b/a \tan(\theta - i) = \tan(\theta - i) /e$. So $\theta = \tan^{-1}(ye/x) + i$
3. Major axis $a = x / \cos(\theta - i)$
4. Using $R^2 =x^2 + y^2$ we get $R^2 = a^2 + (1 - e^2)y^2$

When I use these equations to plot a surface with anything but $i = e = 0$ it gets a weird twisted thing,  not the smooth galaxy shape it's supposed to be: 
[image]

EDIT:
So now I've solved this problem like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sersic_1d(R, mu0, h, n, zp=0):
    exponent = (R / h) **  (1/n)
    I0 = np.exp((zp - mu0) / 2.5)
    return I0 * np.exp(-1.* exponent)

def sersic_2d(x, y, e, i, mu0, h, n, zp=0):
    yp = (x*np.sin(i)) + (y*np.cos(i))
    xp = (x*np.cos(i)) - (y*np.sin(i))
    alpha = np.arctan2(yp,xp*e)
    a = xp / np.cos(alpha)
    R2 = (a*a) + ((1 - (e*e)) * yp*yp)
    return sersic_1d(np.sqrt(R2), mu0, h, n, zp)

def rotate(x, y, angle):
    x1 = x*np.cos(angle) + y*np.sin(angle)
    y1 = y*np.cos(angle) - x*np.sin(angle)
    return x1, y1

def ellipse(x0, y0, a, e, i, theta):
    b = a * (1 - e)
    x = a * np.cos(theta)
    y = b * np.sin(theta)
    x, y = rotate(x, y, i)
    return x + x0, y + y0   

def get_I(x, y, Z):
    return Z[x.astype(int), y.astype(int)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = np.linspace(-100,100,1000)
    nx, ny = np.meshgrid(n, n)
    Z = sersic_2d(nx, ny, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 50, 1, 25)

    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
    a = 100
    x, y = ellipse(0, 0, a, 0.5, 0.5, theta)
    I = get_I(x, y, Z)
    # plt.imshow(Z)
    # plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.plot(I)
    plt.show()
```

However, as you can see. There is a large tracing error. I don't think it's caused by converting to integers since there is large periodicity!

[image: tracing error]

Comment: I have to add this every time I see a figure with the rainbow or spectrum colormap -- please, please, please don't use it. It's a very poor colormap, you can read about reasons why and alternatives [here](http://www.poynter.org/uncategorized/224413/why-rainbow-colors-arent-always-the-best-options-for-data-visualizations/) and [here](http://www.research.ibm.com/people/l/lloydt/color/color.HTM) for just two examples. Or [search for and read](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+rainbow+color+scale+is+bad) many more explanations!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ultimately it is about debugging someone's code and not about physics. Perhaps [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) or [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com) might be better suited for this question?